# How can I "expand"/change the form of the derivatives of Normal PDF and CDF?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am computing the partial derivatives of a likelihood function involving the PDF and CDF of the normal distribution.

I obtain an expression with PDF^(0,1)[NormalDistribution,...] and CDF^(0,1)[NormalDistribution,...], the derivatives of the functions with respect to its second argument.

How can I ask Mathematica to further "transform" these expressions to obtain a final expression that only contains PDF[NormalDistribution,...]?

Thanks for your help!

```
flnl[x1_, x2_] := 
 Log[CDF[NormalDistribution, (x1)]*PDF[NormalDistribution, x1] + 
   CDF[NormalDistribution, x2]*PDF[NormalDistribution, x2 ]]
In[76]:= D[flnl[x1,x2],x1]
Out[76]= (PDF[NormalDistribution,x1] (CDF^(0,1))[NormalDistribution,x1]+CDF[NormalDistribution,x1] (PDF^(0,1))[NormalDistribution,x1])/(CDF[NormalDistribution,x1] PDF[NormalDistribution,x1]+CDF[NormalDistribution,x2] PDF[NormalDistribution,x2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax. See examples in [CDF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html) - Generalizations & Extensions.

You need function brackets, i.e. `NormalDistribution[]`.

```
flnl[x1_, x2_] := 
 Log[CDF[NormalDistribution[], (x1)]*PDF[NormalDistribution[], x1] + 
   CDF[NormalDistribution[], x2]*PDF[NormalDistribution[], x2]]
```